# Furigana font changes?

Tags: discussion

Is it my imagination or has the furigana changed to a different (and, in my opinion, less easy to read) font? I was looking at [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93012/what-is-the-differences-between-%E9%96%93%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%81%86-and-%E9%96%93%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0) and things looked a bit strange.

Comment: Are you talking about both before and after hovering the mouse over the furigana/ruby?

Comment: @dungarian Yes, both cases.